# Was the notifications feature in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ announced?

Tags: discussion, notifications

I like the feature, but it just surprised me.  Did I miss a memo? What should I be looking at to be informed that features or changes like this are on the horizon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the feature was announced in the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/). The blog post is fairly recent and as such it's visible right now in the community bulletin on every Stack Exchange site. Look for that yellow box in the sidebar ;)

You can see it in the question page:

[image]

Comment: But they misspelled *StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™* as *Stack Exchange Genuine dropdown*, so it's understandable that you couldn't find it.

Comment: can i edit your answer and add that image of "Cummunity Bulletin" ?

Comment: @Lucifer Go for it.

Comment: done @YannisRizos